# Twiiter, Webhooks, and Django CRC Check --> 'str' object has no attribute 'xframe_options_exempt'

Tags: django, python-3.x, twitter, webhooks

I am using Django for my webapp and have adapted the tutorial @ https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/subscribe-account-activity/guides/securing-webhooks to run in Python 3 however I am running into this problem in my views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpRequest
import base64, hashlib, hmac, json
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.views.decorators.clickjacking import xframe_options_exempt
from django.views.decorators.http import require_GET


@csrf_exempt
@xframe_options_exempt
def twitter_webhook(request):
    msg = request.GET.get('crc_token')
    msg_bytes = msg.encode()
    sha256_hash_digest = 
    hmac.new(b'bEfpTIneaasdf876asd9f87908709asdf76789689as7dfH', msg_bytes, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
    resp = 'sha256=' + str(sha256_hash_digest)
    twitter_response = {
        'response_token': resp
    }
    return json.dumps(twitter_response)
```

> 'str' object has no attribute 'xframe_options_exempt'

Using pycharm I have debugged step by step through my code and it all works fine returning the appropriate hash up until the point it gets caught by clickjacking middleware.

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/twitter?crc_token=1230983450923485
Django Version: 2.1.4
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'str' object has no attribute 'xframe_options_exempt'
Exception Location:  
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
packages\django\views\decorators\clickjacking.py in wrapped_view, line 51
Python Executable:   
C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.1
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\micha\\Documents\\Projects\\sinclaire_webhooks',
'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 2018.3.1\\helpers\\pydev',
'C:\\Users\\micha\\Documents\\Projects\\sinclaire_webhooks',
'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm '
'2018.3.1\\helpers\\third_party\\thriftpy',
'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 2018.3.1\\helpers\\pydev',
'C:\\Users\\micha\\.PyCharm2018.3\\system\\cythonExtensions',
'C:\\Users\\micha\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\python37.zip',
'C:\\Users\\micha\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\DLLs',
'C:\\Users\\micha\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib',
'C:\\Users\\micha\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37',
'C:\\Users\\micha\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site- packages',
'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm '
'2018.3.1\\helpers\\pycharm_matplotlib_backend']
 Server time:   Sun, 16 Dec 2018 17:58:20 +0000
```

I have searched and can not find anything definitive to lead me towards a resolution with this problem, and being semi new to both python and django any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you're returning a JSON string directly from the view which causes the `xframe_options_exempt` decorator to fall over because it's expecting an `HttpResponse`. Django view functions [should return an `HttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/views/#a-simple-view).

You can modify your view to return an `HttpResponse` like this:

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(twitter_response), content_type='application/json')
```

or alternatively use `JsonResponse` (a subclass of `HttpResponse`) and let Django handle the conversion of the dictionary into JSON:

```
from django.http.response import JsonResponse

...

@csrf_exempt
@xframe_options_exempt
def twitter_webhook(request):
    ...
    twitter_response = {
        'response_token': resp
    }
    return JsonResponse(twitter_response)  # No need to use json.dumps()
```

Comment: You sir are a gentleman and a scholar thank you for the help I spent a day and a half on this.